# Validate multiple conditions in Yii2

Tags: php, validation, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have this kind of validation on `Leave Employee`:

1. Validate if `startdate` less than `applydate` (done).
2. Cannot apply leave if `maximumquota` less than 0 (done).
3. If `status = approved`, `maximumquota - daysleave` (done).

I want to add another validation on applying when `startdate` inputted exists and is approved. `startdate = startdate + daysleave`, on form `status=rejected`.

I already made an algorithm like this:

```
if(startdate='startdate' between startdate(Y-m-(d+'daysleave')->where('status'=='approved')
{
    $_post = 'status'=rejected,
        'applydate=date('Y-m-d'),
        'startdate';
    )
} else {

}
```

This is my Create controller:

```
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())){
    if($model->daysleaveleft(Yii::$app->user->id,date('Y',strtotime($model->startdate)))>0)
    {
        //Edited
        if($model->startdate < max($s))
        {
            $model->status='2';
        }//
        if($model->startdate < $model->applydate)
        {
            echo "Error !";
        }
        else
        {
            $model->save();
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $model->status='2';
    }
} 
else
{
    return $this->render('create', ['model' => $model,]);
}
```

And my Leave model:

```
public function DaysLeaveLeft($id, $year) {
    $models = Leave::find()->select(['daysleave'=>'sum(daysleave)'])->where(['status'=>'approved','EmpId' => $id,'year(startdate)'=>$year])->One();
    $Setting = Setting::find()->where(['Var'=>'MaxLeave'])->One();
    return $Setting->Val - $models['daysleave'];  
}
```

Comment: Ehm, a little confusing. Can you give some more examples/code? It would make easier to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The steps I used to make this work:

1. Make an SQL query to get end of Leave days, for example, if `startdate = 03-08-2016`, then `enddate = startdate + Leave Days`.

   ```
   ALTER FUNCTION enddays(@Id bigint)
   RETURNS VARCHAR(10)
   AS BEGIN
   DECLARE @st DATE, @long INT,@Var VARCHAR(10)='0',@cekId INT =0
   SELECT @cekId=id,@st=startdate,@long=leavedays FROM leave WHERE id=@Id  
   IF @cekId > 0 BEGIN
   SELECT @long +=COUNT(dt)
   FROM calendar WHERE cast(dt as date) BETWEEN cast(@st as dt) and  cast(DATEADD(day,@long,@st) as date)
   set @Var = CAST(CAST(DATEADD(DAY,@long,@st) AS DATE) AS VARCHAR(10))
   END
   RETURN @Var
   END
   ```
2. Then make a procedure:

   ```
   ALTER procedure endleave
   @id bigint
   as
   BEGIN
   SELECT dbo.endays(l.id) from leave l
   WHERE GETDATE() < CAST(dbo.enddays(l.id) as date) 
   and EmpId=@id
   and status= 1
   END
   ```
3. Add this to `leavecontroller`:

   ```
   $id=Yii::$app->user->id;
   $query="exec endleave @id=$id";
   $command=Yii::$app->db->createCommand($query);
   $s = $command->queryAll();
   ```
4. Edit the controller.

   ```
   if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
       if($model->daysleaveleft(Yii::$app->user->id,date('Y',strtotime($model->startdate)))>0) {
           //Edited
           if($model->startdate < max($s)) {
               $model->status = '2';
           }
           if($model->startdate < $model->applydate) {
               echo "Error !";
           } else {
               $model->save();
               return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
           }
       } else {
           $model->status = '2';
       }
   }  else {
       return $this->render('create', ['model' => $model,]);
   }
   ```